# How to call a function of one activity from another activity without creating new object of the activity being called?

Tags: android

I created `activity1` and called `activity2` from the `activity1`.Now i wish to call function of `activity1` staying at `activity2` and "without initializing instant of `activity1`" in order to avoid recreated of `activity 1` again.I want to know the code in `callfirst()` of my second activity

**here is my mainactivity**

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button button1 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton1);
        button1.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => firstload ();
    }
    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState (outState);
    }
    public void firstload()
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(first));
    }
```

**here is my first activity**

```
    public class first : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.first);
        Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnfirst);
        btn.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => loadsecond();
    }

    public void loadsecond()
    {
        StartActivity (typeof(second));
    }
     public void message()
    {
        Toast.MakeText (this, "fxn of activityfirst called from     activitysecond", ToastLength.Short).Show ();        
    }
}
```

**here is my second activity**

```
public class second : Activity
{

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.second);
        Button btn = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnsecond);
        btn.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) => callfirst();       
    }
    public void callfirst()
    {
      //what should i do here ???
    }
```

}

Comment: The correct solution depends on: "why do you want to call the method of the first activity from second? What do you want to do?"

Comment: i am coding in xamarain.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to use some common functions and global variables, better create a class that holds them - like `Globals.java`. There you can have your global variables:

```
public static String someGlobalString = "";
public static void someGlobalFunction(){ };
```

and you can call them from your code like:

```
Globals.someGlobalString = "some value";
Globals.someGlobalFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create that method static and call with that class name itself coz static method and variable is calling from that class name itself

Answer (score 0):

aYou can indeed use static methods for this purpose, but you should not use activities for static methods to be used by other activities. That is not how they are supposed to work. They should be separate entities which can pass messages to each other using the Binder framework. If you do need to have access to the same method, then simply create another class which has that static method available to both activities.

Comment: using a static method is not calling an activity "like this"